# Optimizing sql update syntax rather than the Server

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle11g, query-optimization

There are two tables, one is getting updated based on second table. The SQL is working but it is taking too much time because of number of records, i think. See [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b47e/3) fiddle. The actual master table contains 1,500,000 and child contains 700,000 records and the following sql kept executing for 4 hours, hence terminated.

```
UPDATE master m SET m.amnt = (SELECT amnt FROM child c WHERE c.seqn = m.seqn)
WHERE m.seqn IN (SELECT seqn FROM child);
```

The execution plan of this sql is (Red one is master, other is child)

[image]

`seqn` is the primary key. No doubt it all depends upon server's performance and stats of indices. However, It bothers me that master is not being accessed by the index and child is being read twice. It is possible that the sql is optimized but oracle decided to go in this way, however i tried to optimize the sql as

```
UPDATE (
SELECT m.seqn m_seqn,c.seqn c_seqn, c.amnt c_amnt, m.amnt m_amnt
FROM master m INNER JOIN child c ON m.seqn = c.seqn) 
SET m_amnt = c_amnt
```

which resulted in following error

```
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved 
table : UPDATE ( SELECT m.seqn m_seqn,c.seqn c_seqn, c.amnt c_amnt, m.amnt m_amnt 
FROM master m INNER JOIN child c ON m.seqn = c.seqn) SET m_amnt = c_amnt
```

Is there any way i can optimize the SQL other than updating stats and tuning up the server?

**EDIT** The solution by @Sebas will not work if the column to be JOINED ON is not PK

Answer (score 2):

check this one out:

```
UPDATE  
(
    SELECT m.amnt AS tochange, c.amnt AS newvalue 
    FROM child c 
        JOIN master m ON c.seqn = m.seqn
) t
SET t.tochange = t.newvalue;

SELECT * FROM master;
```

fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c6b73/2

you just missed the PK in the fiddle.

Comment: Hmmm, the basic difference is that in my case `seqn` is `not null` and `unique index` but not `primary key`. Hence, It shows that `Primary Key` and `Unique Index + Not Null` are different!!!

Comment: interesting indeed. at least for this kind of operations!

Comment: Even after modifying `seqn` as `Primary Key` it is still giving the same error probably because my version is 11.1 and sqlfiddle is using 11.2.

Comment: So intriguing, could you investigate?

Comment: Interesting! The query will work if `child`'s `seqn` is either `Unique` or `Primary Key`. Nothing is required for master at all

Comment: As it should do. You select master records which you want to update, so it must be guaranteed that the join to child doesn't multiply master records. A unique constraint on seqn does exactly that.

Comment: Time may be saved in case some master values equal the child values already: WHERE DECODE(m.amnt, c.amnt, 1, 0) = 0

Comment: The suggested query won't work if the column to be JOINED ON is not PK!